# How to make first sub-component of react-table open by default and open other sub-components manually

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

Here are nested react-tables.
First time when i render react-table , first sub-component should be open by default and also i should be manually able to open sub-components of other rows.

I tried with setting

```js
<ReactTable
  data={arr[]}
  expanded={{0:true}}
  columns={...}
  subcomponent={row => {
    return (
      <div >
        <ReactTable
          data={arr[]}
          expanded={{0:true}}
          columns={...}
          subcomponent={row => {
            return(<div>{...}</div>)
        />
      </div>
     )
   }}
/>
```

The above code is making my first row sub-component to be open by default but, I am not able to open any other row sub-components .

So, can anyone please help me by providing the solution for this.

Comment: Can you create stackbliz example with sample data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "defaultExpanded" property, such as:

```
<ReactTable
  data={arr[]}
  defaultExpanded={{0:true}}
  columns={...}
  subcomponent={row => {
    return (
      <div >
        <ReactTable
          data={arr[]}
          expanded={{0:true}}
          columns={...}
          subcomponent={row => {
            return(<div>{...}</div>)
        />
      </div>
     )
   }}
/>
```

The "defaultExpanded" will expand, by default, the row index that you sent as params, and it also allows the react-table to collapse/hide any other row.